# Remove schema name prefix in the output sql of liquibase updateSQL

Tags: liquibase, gradle-plugin

I use liquibase version 4.23.1 together with the plugin 2.2.0 for gradle 7.6.1

When running the updateSQL task, the generated sql statements include the user or schema name used (MYSCHEMA):

`CREATE TABLE MYSCHEMA.sergio_test (id VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO MYSCHEMA.DATABASECHANGELOG (ID, AUTHOR, FILENAME, DATEEXECUTED, ORDEREXECUTED, MD5SUM, DESCRIPTION, COMMENTS, EXECTYPE, CONTEXTS, LABELS, LIQUIBASE, DEPLOYMENT_ID) VALUES (...);
`

Is there any way to avoid this? In past versions this prefix was not included.

Thanks!!

I tried some parameters like

includeSchema false

--outputDefaultSchema=false --outputDefaultCatalog=false

, unsuccesfully